# python: import flat text file without delimiters

Tags: python, regex, text, import

I want to import into Python a text file extracted from some database. It is a flat text format, without end of line separators (but I know there are supposed to be a fixed number of columns).
Each new line is identified with an incremented id (`"0001"`, `"0002"`, `"0003"` in the example below).

I tried different methods, eventually this one:

```
with open('url.txt', "rb") as f:
    df = f.read().decode(errors="replace")
```

But this gives me a gigantic string… I then tried some regex to split on the Id with a loop and then sub-split on `","`, the problem is that sometimes missing data is coded `\N` without quotes and it never returns the same number of columns per row. Sample of data:

```
"0001","2015-01-01","doc","eab4e80fec7352a7","https://www.paypal.com/us","setRequestHeader(\"Content-Type\")","0002","2015-01-02","doc","0",\N,\N,"0003",etc.
```

the expected output should be a pandas dataframe with columns: id, date, doctype, hash, url, code.
Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: can you please provide the screenshot of how the file looks like, once you open it in a file editor?

Comment: Have you tried `df.split(',')`? Then you just have to avoid the `'\\N'` values, but you have the right number of columns.

Comment: @dexter thanks. I Don't think i can because of the confidentiality, but in text editor it starts really just like my example...

Comment: what do you mean by "avoid the \\N values"?.

Comment: Something like that: `df = df.replace('\\N', '""')`

Comment: oh ok! good idea, thanks, it seems to work on a sample; let me try on the full dataset and i come back to you. (but anyway, do you think that there is no simpler way or built in function to import such data?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you dataframe, you can do somthing like this:

```
with open('testfloat', "rb") as f:
    df = f.read().decode(errors="replace")
df = df.replace('\\N', '""')  # Replace \N by empty strings
df = df[1:-1]  # remove first and last "
df_list = df.split('","')  # Splitting values

array = [df_list[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(df_list), 6)]  # Extract the lines

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
```

Comment: ok, so with this I Don't even need to split by `Id` first, right?

Comment: Indeed, because you always have a fixed number of columns.

Comment: & pleasure to be helped by a former "BJ-men" ;-) been there too!

Comment: Haha pleasure for me too! ;-)